# Group by Customer ID where Another Column is only Contains a specific set of Values

Tags: group-by

Wasn't sure how to ask this one.

I have table with 4 columns in it.  They are PK, CustomerID, Language, and Date.  The Customer ID can be the same for multiple rows in the file. The Language is a numerical value from 1-8 representing different languages. The Date is the first of any given month.  So, for 10 rows in the table, it is legitimate for the CustomerID to be 123 for all 10 rows, the language '1' for all ten rows, and the date '1/1/2015' for all 10 rows.  Essentially, I have a lot of subsets in this table where the PK would create a row level distinction.

On to what I am trying to do.  I need to group by the customer ID, for 3 specific dates ('10/01/2015', '11/01/2015', '12/01/2015'), where the only value found for language is 1.  Meaning, if on 10/01/05, customerID 123 has 10 rows and 9 are language '1', and the 10th row is language '2', I wouldn't want that to return in my results.

At the end, I need a list of the customer ID's that from those 3 dates that only have '1' as there language and do not have any other languages in their rows.

This has gotten beyond my skill.  I appreciate any help as I feel like it is simpler than I am making it out to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Language = 1 AND (Date = date1 OR Date = date2 OR Date = date3) GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: The problem I would run into there is the CustomerID would be included just because it found a row where language is '1'.  It wouldn't mean that other rows don't exist for the same customerID and date that are marked as something other than '1'. That's where I hit a wall on this end.  I need to only return customer ID's if all the rows found during those dates for that particular customerID are '1' and not anything else.

Comment: It seems to me your need for a complex query only stems from the fact that your db design is not very solid. Even if you add a PK to the table, if you have rows with exactly the same content, something could have been done differently.

Comment: No every row is the same content, but the design makes sense for it's use. the Table does have a primary key.  The table is full of names and addresses.  The customerID column would be the same for multiple rows, but the person's name, address, etc. would be different.  The language is the person's primary spoken language. I need to isolate customerID's where the primary language spoken for all persons is only 1 (English) and there are no person's speaking other languages (2-8 values). Hope that helps and thanks for taking a look.

Comment: But that's my point, that just doesn't seem like a sensible design. One customer ID should belong to just one customer, whether that's a person or a company. Several people might be able to represent a customer but that still doesn't make them customers themselves, otherwise they should get their own ID. Do yourself a favor and create a better design.

Comment: Having said that, what you are trying to achieve is still possible. 1) Subquery all records for customerID 2) Count query for language >1 and depending on result (CASE WHEN statement), you can return the customerId or not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll work on putting that together from this side.

Comment: For the design, does not the primary key in the table provide the uniqueness you are suggesting needs to be present? It might be my own table design ignorance (I didn't design this one or anything in our DB).  The customer ID does belong to one customer in the customers table, but this table presents contacts for the customer.  Those two are linked together through the foreign key of customer ID.

Comment: If there indeed is a customers table and the customerID in this table is just the foreign key to that one, then your setup is generally fine. Still, if you ended up with completely identical rows (ignoring PK), then something is not done right. The purpose of a special PK column is not to create uniqueness but to make it easier to reference information.